# How to avoid mixed language names in QGIS Cloud?

Tags: qgis-cloud

I have a project uploaded into QGIS Cloud. When I load it from the web browser, the German name of "United Kingdom" is displayed but all other places in the UK have their English names:

[image: UK map]

If I zoom in a little, the English name is used and I would to have this maintained without having to zoom in/out constantly.

Is this possible?